# Can I use VS2010 TFS Power Tools PowerShell cmdlets to directly get the contents of a Source Control file into a variable?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, powershell-2.0, tfs-power-tools

I want to use the latest contents of a XAML file stored in TFS Source Control and embed it in a string variable, which is to be submitted as a query to MS SQL Server.

I have been using TFS Power Tools cmdlets in PowerShell (such as Get-TfsChildItem and Select-TfsItem) to successfully get handles on TFS files, changesets and shelvesets. But I cannot identify any methods or properties on these objects that would allow me to directly get the contents of a file into a variable.

I want to do something like this:

```
$tfsFileName = "$/MyBranch/MyFile.xaml"
$tfsServerName = "http://myTFSServer:8080/tfs"
$tfsServer = Get-TfsServer $tfsServerName

$xamlFile = Get-TfsChildItem -Item $tfsFileName -Server $tfsServer

$xamlContent = (Get-Content $xamlFile)
```

Is this possible, or do I always have to perform a Get Latest using tf.exe, and then get the contents of the local file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the [`DownloadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138502%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method on an [`Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.item%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  Eg:

```
$xamlFile = Get-TfsChildItem -Item $tfsFileName -Server $tfsServer
$xamlFile.DownloadFile("C:\Temp\file.xaml")
```

Comment: I tried calling that method and got this error message:Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "1" argument(s): "Team Foundation services are not available from server http://myTFSServer:8080/tfs.
Technical information (for administrator):
  Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection'."

Answer (score 0):

When I got the message about Team Foundation Services not being available on  my server it turns out I had the wrong URI.  I originally had http://tfs.mycompanyweb.mycompany.com:8080/tfs/ist/ISTDatabaseTools but changed it to http://tfs.mycompanyweb.mycompany.com:8080/tfs/ist and that error cleared up.

I still fail to get DownloadFile to work properly though.  I'm trying to do something similar myself.

Joe